# Using feature service with JavaScript API and ArcGIS for Server on localhost?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.2, feature-service, offline

I installed ArcGIS 10.2 for Server on my localhost and created and published a feature service on it. Now I want to use the feature service I created on a simple html page using Javascript. How can I do that?

I read the resources on arcgis.com but it just described how to do it with the maps on arcgis.com!

I don't need a base map from arcgis.com. actually I want to use the web page offline(just on localhost).

Answer (score 4):

To create a feature layer, you need access to the layer's REST endpoint. This can be on the web, or on your localhost - see [The Services Directory and the REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_rest.html).

See the [Feature Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) help page to get started with creating a feature layer using the ArcGIS Server JS API - the URL you use can point to your local machine.

Comment: can you help me with a simple example?

Comment: [Here](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=fl_ondemand) is an example in the Esri sandbox, showing how to create a feature layer. Change the URL on line 40 (`var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(...`) to point to your local host's ArcGIS Server